# Fullcalendar: Is it possible if I would like to display today in the first cell of calendar in month view

Tags: fullcalendar, angular8, fullcalendar-4

I'm using the fullcalendar v4 and angular 8.

As current calendar feature, the month view always show the range of date in the month which is showing, it might have some date of previous month or next month due to 30 or 31 days for a month.

I would like to move today date to first cell of month view.
For example:
Today is 16 Dec 2020, so i would like the month view should start at 16 Dec 2020 and end at 16 Jan 2021 ( it means the 16 Dec 2020 would be at the first cell of calendar

Comment: No this isn't possible with the month view unfortunately. Perhaps you can make a feature request - details of how to do that are on the fullCalendar website

Comment: Hi ADyson, thanks for your response. It's sad to hear that.

Comment: Remember that it's an open source project, so you could always consider contributing the necessary code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Full Calendar V4, then you should set `showNonCurrentDates: false`. It hides previous and next month's days and also does not pass the previous/next month's dates in the events URL.

Comment: Hi @Danis, thanks for your response. The problem is month view always contain date range of showing month as if the month is December then month view will contain 1-Dec-2020 -> 31-Dec-2020. But now I just want the month view should start from current date ( aka today ) to further 31 days. For example : Today is 17-Dec-2020, then month view should start at 17-Dec-2020 then end at 18-Jan-2021.